# I would like to input data based on categories in Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get the output in image 1, such that whenever I select book as itemcategory and type my code or barcode all data such as itemname and itemprice etc go under book category and new code/barcode.

[image: image1]

What I currently have is in image2. If I input data again under book it just replaces the data already there, it doesn't add a new record based on category and (code/itembarcode)- both these are same.

[image: image2]

```js
function insertData(){
  set(ref(db, "ItemByCategory/" +category.value),{
    Code: barcode.value,
    Category: category.value,
    ItemName: itemname.value,
    ItemPrice: itemprice.value,
  })
  .then(() =>{
    alert("data stored successfully");
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    alert("unsuccessful, error"+error);
  });
}
```

This is my insert code.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your want:

```
set(ref(db, "ItemByCategory/" +category.value+"/"+barcode.value),{
  Code: barcode.value,
  Category: category.value,
  ItemName: itemname.value,
  ItemPrice: itemprice.value,
})
```

Or, with a ES6 template literal:

```
set(ref(db, `ItemByCategory/${category.value}/${barcode.value}`,{
  ...
})
```